# PHP parse error with no explanation

Tags: php, php-parse-error

PHP is giving me a parse error here.

```
if ($detalleReserva->isGratis() || $detalleReserva->isPasajeroSinCosto()){
    $cantPaxGratis++;
}
```

> Parse error: parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/versioned/software/tur/liquidacionHead.php on line 58

The if line is line 58. I've tried changing de `||` with `OR`  but the same. If I change the second part (after || ) for a '1' or a '0' it works fine.

Extra information:

```
function isPasajeroSinCosto() {
     return ($this->tipo == 4);
}
```

PHP version:

> PHP 7.1.0 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2016 03:30:24) ( NTS )

Comment: What is the output from `$detalleReserva->isPasajeroSinCosto()` ?

Comment: I've added the function @KhorneHoly

Comment: if you pasted all the relevant code, maybe just maybe we'd of pasted that in our (code) editors and would have seen that hidden (unicode) character, which I suspect is what it is. Because nothing in what you posted shows it.

Comment: I am not understanding the function isPasajeroSinCosto() because in this function what are you returning? ($this->tipo == 4) is a comparing situation. what will it return?

Comment: if the class variable tipo is equal to 4, then the function returns true, false otherwise

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using mac, and when pressing || and then space to quick (maybe pressing alt), an unknown character (invisible) get into the code and broke it.

Comment: Yes, may I add that `||` and `OR` are *exactly* the **same**. (you stated that you tried changing that, in your question)